# Null DateTime variable

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to read a field from SQL DB which is `DateTime` datatype but that value is NULL.

```
DateTime STime = NULL;
```

The receiving variable from C# is this

```
public Nullable<DateTime> StartTime { get; set; }
```

When I'm trying to read:

```
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    StartTime = reader.GetDateTime(7);
}
```

Can anyone help on how to retrieve data from the database which is null to C#?

Comment: What happens when you try to read?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the call to `GetDateTime` can return null, you must first

> Call IsDBNull to check for null values before calling this method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getdatetime(v=vs.110).aspx

If IsDBNull returns true, set StartTime to *null*.

This is a fairly common situation.  I have written extension methods to make it easier to handle this pattern, e.g.:

```
    public static DateTime? GetDateTimeOrNull(this IDataReader reader, int ordinal)
    {
        return reader.IsDBNull(ordinal) ? null : (DateTime?)reader.GetDateTime(ordinal);
    }
```

If you have that extension method in your project, you would change

```
StartTime = reader.GetDateTime(7);
```

to

```
StartTime = reader.GetDateTimeOrNull(7);
```

As an aside, I recommend not using hard-coded numbers for the ordinal.  Instead, before you start looping through the reader, do something like `int idxTS = reader.GetOrdinal("TheTSColumn");` and then in the loop `StartTime = reader.GetDateTimeOrNull(idxTS);`.  That protects your code from changes e.g. adding/removing a column from the query.

Comment: So you mean to say, I need to make Nullable<DateTime> StartTime into DateTime? StartTime?